# How to make Arrays.stream with a List of JSONObject

Tags: java

I have a list of JSONObjects 
to which I add a JSON object to each iteration. At the end I would like to have a JSON Object list which I wanted to do a group by using collectors except that Arrays.stream does not take into account a list. So I tried to declare a JSONObject array and add to it the list but the grouping by does not work. Is there another solution?

The list of JSONObject

```
List<JSONObject> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

The array to added to Arrays.stream

```
 JSONObject[] examples = null;
while (traficCursor.hasNext()) {

        try {
            wordsArray = traficCursor.next().get("Date").toString().split("\\s+");
            String[] fieldNames = {"Date", "Heure"};
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
                data.add(new JSONObject().put(fieldNames[i],wordsArray[i]));
                data.add(new JSONObject().put("debit",traficCursor.next().get("debit")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    while (infoClimatCursor.hasNext()) {
        for (String mapKeyInfo : infoClimatCursor.next().keySet()) {
            try {
                data.add(new JSONObject().put(mapKeyInfo,infoClimatCursor.next().get(mapKeyInfo)));

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }
    }
    }
```

Adding the list to the array

```
    examples = new JSONObject[]{
            new JSONObject(data)
    };
    try {
```

Grouping By Date

```
        Map<Object, List<JSONObject>> groupbydate = Arrays.stream(examples)
                .map(json -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(json.getString("Date"), json))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
        groupbydate.entrySet().forEach(gbd -> System.out.println(gbd.getValue()));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: If you have a ``List`` object, then it has already a ``stream()`` function. No need to make an array.

Comment: you mean data.stream() ?

Comment: Yes. It provides a ``Stream<JSONObject>``, as an ``Arrays.stream(JSONObject[])`` would.